# SQL Server : get day of month from Year Month WeekOfMonth

Tags: sql-server

I have a complicated calendar report coming from a SQL query where I have the year, month and WeekNumOfMonth (meaning the week number from the beginning of the month).

I need a function to return the DayOfMonth (ie: values of between 1-28,29,30 or 31 depending on the month) given Year, month and WeekNumOfMonth.

I have seen functions that do this given WeekNum from beginning of year but I only have WeekNum of the given month. I just can't seem to give the datePart and dateAdd functions right. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please show a sample of some dates and desired outputs as from what you've said, I can't see anyway of determining the day of the month if you only have the week, as surely it's going to be 1 of 7 days? what logic are you going to use to narrow this down? do you just want the first day?

Comment: Combination year + month + number of week in month will not give you day. It will give you whole seven days in that week instead.

Comment: my query is a follows
SELECT TOP [YR],[MonthNum],[WeekOfMonth],[sun],[mo],[tu],[we],[th],[fr],[sa]FROM [vwBookingsForMonth]
so there is one row for each week of the month of the year. If I introduce the date then the data is joined multiple times.
I am trying to fill a scheduling control with bookings for a month in a very compact format so that it can be printed easily.

I am going to try @arunprasanth1111 suggestion and I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

> Note : Combination of Year ,Month ,Week Number will not give you the
> day name  because a week contain more than one day so how can you find
> which day is it ? it is not possible

**example :** `year 2015 month 06 week number 1`

then it has a combination of

```
1 monday 
2  tuesday
3 wednesday
4 thursday
5 friday 
6 saturday
```

then with these results how can you predit the exact day ??

Else need some conditions or restrictions

If you have Year, Month , and date then you can find the day name using the below query it will give the start and end date of the week then you can take the dates from start date and end with end date

```
SELECT (
  DATENAME(dw, 
  CAST(DATEPART(m, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) 
  + '/' 
  + CAST(DATEPART(d, '2015-06-23') AS VARCHAR) 
  + '/' 
  + CAST(DATEPART(yy, getdate()) AS VARCHAR))
  )
```

**Update**

If you need all days between the current week then use the following query

```
DECLARE
    @Year INT,
    @Week INT,
    @FirstDayOfYear DATETIME,
    @FirstMondayOfYear DATETIME,
    @StartDate DATETIME,
    @EndDate DATETIME

SET @Year = 2015
SET @Week = 24// week number is based on year and it is not based on month

-- Get the first day of the provided year.
SET @FirstDayOfYear = CAST('1/1/' + CAST(@YEAR AS VARCHAR) AS DATETIME)

-- Get the first monday of the year, then add the number of weeks.
SET @FirstMondayOfYear = DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, DATEADD(DAY, 6 - DATEPART(DAY, @FirstDayOfYear), @FirstDayOfYear)), 0)

SET @StartDate = DATEADD(WEEK, @Week - 1, @FirstMondayOfYear)

-- Set the end date to one week past the start date.
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(WEEK, 1, @StartDate)

SELECT @StartDate AS StartDate, DATEADD(SECOND, -1, @EndDate) AS EndDate
```

**Update**

if do not have the year week number then use the below query

```
DATEPART(WEEK,'2015-06-01')
```

The above query is one example

In the query you have two values that is `Year` and `Month`

> you need only the third value that means date
>
> as a technique you can give 01 as the date then it will give the
> starting week number your selected month

here it will result 23 so you got the idea in **2015 - month 06 starts with week number 23** so then you can easily do your stuff

Idea : if your week number is 1 then take 23 as week if it is 2 then 24 like wise..

Comment: OP very clearly says "I only have WeekNum of the given month." This will not work for him

Comment: i hope if he have week number and month number then he can find the week number of the year ..you are right i will not provide the code for doing that .but he can do that if he take some effor ..am i right ? correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Hard to say. If the month starts on a Thursday, then do the first three days make week one of the month or not?

Comment: you are right first 3 days make the week ...so u say it is not possible to get the year week from month and week number of month ???

Comment: The first four days of the same week would be in the previous month. Possible, but will be pretty complex, I think

Comment: ok raj i will check that and let you know if i can do that ..thanks for your valid comments

Comment: @Raj we can do that select DATEPART(WEEK,'2015-06-01') by using this query

Comment: @Raj i hope now the problem is solved , thanks for your valid point, inform me if any more clarification is needed in the answer

Comment: my final query is as follows: SELECT [YR]
      ,[MonthNum]
      ,[WeekOfMonth]
      ,[su]
      ,[mo]
      ,[tu]
      ,[we]
      ,[th]
      ,[fr]
      ,[sa]
  FROM [vwBookingsForMonthFinal]